# Publishing on my Facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, feed, publish, facebook-page

I'm developing an ios(6) app that publish on Facebook.
I can publish on my wall, but I cannot publish on my fan page.
Seems that the problem is on the authorization that my facebook app should have on my fan page, but I don't understand where give this authorization!

I've changed the parameter of destination of feed from "me/feed" to `/<PAGE_ID>/feed` but without results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get `manage_pages` permission from user. After permission, you can use `/<PAGE_ID>/feed` endpoint for post feed to a page that the user administrates.

Comment: Check line that call the graph api. Maybe it is still `me/feed`

Comment: I've found the error: I must to check also the 'publish_stream' into 'extended_permissions'
Thank for your support

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have checked "publish_stream" and "manage pages" permission in "extended_permissions" section.

Use [facebook graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)  to check your code